# Form submitting wrongfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submission

I am using a script to validate a few form fields before the form is submitted. The script is supposed to return false if the validations failed. On linux the script works fine in FF, Chrome and Opera. On windows the script fails and the forms is submitted on Chrome, Safari and IE. 
Your thoughtswill be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    // Place ID's of all required fields in the array.
    required=["formname","formemail"];
    email = $("#formemail");
    name = $("#formname");
    errornotice = $("#error");
    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

    $("#suggestionform").submit( function(){
         //validate required fields
         for(i =  0; i < required.length; i++){
             var input = $('#'+required[i]);
             if( (input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)){
                 input.addClass("needsfilled");
                 input.val(emptyerror);
                 errornotice.fadeIn(750);
             }else {
                 input.removeClass("needsfilled");
             }
         }         
         if( !/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())){
             email.addClass("needsfilled");
             email.val(emailerror);
         }         
         if ( "" == name.val()){
             name.addClass("needsfilled");
             name.val(emptyerror);
         }
         if( $("#link1").val() + $("#link2").val() + $("#link3").val() + $("#link4").val() +  $("#textarea1").val() + $("#textarea2").val() == "") {
             errornotice.fadeIn(750);
             alert("returning fail")
             return false;
         }
         if( $(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")){
             alert("returning fail here")
             return false;
         }else{errornotice.hide();return true;}      
    });   

    $(":input").focus( function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled")){
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    })    
});





Version 2
 var required=["formname","formemail"];
var email = $("#formemail");
var name = $("#formname");
var errornotice = $("#error");
// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
var emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
var emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

function suggestionSubmit(theform){
    required=["formname","formemail"];
    email = $("#formemail");
    name = $("#formname");
    errornotice = $("#error");
    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";    

    for(i =  0; i < required.length; i++){
             var input = $('#'+required[i]);
             if( (input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)){
                 input.addClass("needsfilled");
                 input.val(emptyerror);
                 errornotice.fadeIn(750);
             }else {
                 input.removeClass("needsfilled");
             }
         }         
     if( !/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())){
         email.addClass("needsfilled");
         email.val(emailerror);
     }         
     if ( "" == name.val()){
         name.addClass("needsfilled");
         name.val(emptyerror);
     }
     if( $("#link1").val() + $("#link2").val() + $("#link3").val() + $("#link4").val() +  $("#textarea1").val() + $("#textarea2").val() == "") {
         errornotice.fadeIn(750);
         return false
     }
     if( $(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")){
         return false;
     }
     else{errornotice.hide();return true;}     
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to fix it?  Which fields does it fail on?  All of them?

Comment: I've tried putting alerts where the script would return false to test if actually see the code. I left a couple of them in the code. Even after the form is submitted I would see the error messages in the input field (using sessions there) and the errorline that fades in is appears for a brief moment then the form is submitted. which makes me think the script is doing what it aught to but the form is still submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write smth like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
// Place ID's of all required fields in the array.
required=["formname","formemail"];
email = $("#formemail");
name = $("#formname");
errornotice = $("#error");
// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

$("#suggestionform").submit( function(event){
     //validate required fields
     for(i =  0; i < required.length; i++){
         var input = $('#'+required[i]);
         if( (input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)){
             input.addClass("needsfilled");
             input.val(emptyerror);
             errornotice.fadeIn(750);
         }else {
             input.removeClass("needsfilled");
         }
     }         
     if( !/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())){
         email.addClass("needsfilled");
         email.val(emailerror);
     }         
     if ( "" == name.val()){
         name.addClass("needsfilled");
         name.val(emptyerror);
     }
     if( $("#link1").val() + $("#link2").val() + $("#link3").val() + $("#link4").val() +  $("#textarea1").val() + $("#textarea2").val() == "") {
         errornotice.fadeIn(750);
         alert("returning fail")
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
     }
     if( $(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")){
         alert("returning fail here")
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
     }else{errornotice.hide();return true;}      
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps. But now the form does not submit at all. I made 
 event.preventDefault(); the first line of the code and put the event argument in the function.

Comment: Sorry I submitted not complete example. You need to use event.preventDefault() in case you want form to not be submitted. Answer is updated.

Comment: I actually tried this right after putting it on the first line. Using it conditionally still does not stop the form from submitting. Whats beating me is why it works on some browsers/os and not the other. This is how the form is submitted:
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width:100px"/>
pretty standard stuff.

Comment: So you see alerts like "returning fail" or "returning fail here"? If not then there is something wrong with IF conditions.

Comment: No alerts so I tried to rework the way the script ran a little. What I did is allow the form to make an explicit function call and return the value to onsubmit like so:
    onsubmit="return functioncall(this);"
Now the script works with IE, FF and Opera(on windows), but still not in Chrome or safari(on windows). Bizarre!

See version 2 below the original code.

Comment: You can check in chrome javascript console following if statements
$("#link1").val() + $("#link2").val() + $("#link3").val() + $("#link4").val() +  $("#textarea1").val() + $("#textarea2").val() == ""

and

$(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")

If they returns false in Chrome, then the problem inside them, you can rework them, or post html and I will help.

I think that :input should be changed to input.

Comment: OK. I will post an update when I get home (don't have access to anything really from on work).

Comment: I have resorted to basic dom selection. IE and Safari still submits the form
    `code`if( $("#formname").hasClass("needsfilled") || $("#formemail").hasClass("needsfilled") )
            {
                alert("failed");
                return false;
            }`code`
I commented out the entire section with the links and focus on the other part. No success. The selector is supported here: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: I had some help and I found the solution. The problem was I did not put var in front of the variables. For whatever reason it seems to stop the eerie behavior in Chrome, IE and Safari. Much thanks for you help.